# Black screen after upgrading Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I upgraded my kali by doing `apt upgrade`. Now when I try to start up my kali in virtualbox,after logging in, I just see a black screen and nothing happens. Could you help, please?

Comment: What operating system you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it prompting for a username & password? if it is not please use this method to switch to cli :

To switch back to text mode, simply press CTRL+ALT+F1. This will not stop your graphical session, it will simply switch you back to the terminal you logged in at. You can switch back to the graphical session with CTRL+ALT+F7.

- after switching to CLI , apply this command as it seems that the upgrade fails.

  ```
  # apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Comment: there is not any interface to write something :(

Comment: I edited my answer, could you please check and feedback

Comment: nothing happens,it's like my kali ui is literally dead and my internet connection is too slow for redownloading it

Comment: do you have any desk  installed .... i can login remotely and check ... send your anydesk id

Comment: oh wait,it worked,when I see the black screen,I clicked CTRL+ALT+F1,now I'm in the terminal without any gui? Can I revert today's upgrade from here?

Comment: do you have discord? Can we talk from there please?

Comment: if you dont have discord here is my anydesk id 950 357 033

Comment: here is my discord username nour.alkharraz#5475